# Handling newlines within sed; command called from Python

Tags: python, regex, bash, sed, subprocess

I am having an issue with newlines in my command which involves the use of `sed`.

The scenario is as follows. When I execute the following command from Bash, I get:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed -e s/ph/\\nPH/g | grep -v ^$

PHysical id : 0core id      : 0
PHysical id : 0core id      : 1
```

As you can see, the `sed` command replaced *ph* with *\nPH*, such that I get a new line for each 'physical id...'

Now, I am calling this bash command from Python. Here is a small snippet of my code containing all relevant library imports.

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed -e s/ph/\\nPH/g | grep -v ^$ '
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is that I get:

```
nPHysical id    : 0core id      : 0nPHysical id : 0core id      : 1
```

on one line. It appears that the '*\n*' is not processed as the letter *n* is printed before *PH*.

I need to get the output nicely printed so that I can later add `| sort | uniq | wc -l` to my command to count the lines.

I would appreciate some help from the Bash-and-Python gurus out there.

Thank you.

Comment: You just need to escape your escape some more. `\\\\n` or wrap the sed command in quotes `sed -e \'s/ph/\\nPH/g\'`.

Comment: You should not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `egrep`,`awk` etc.  You can change this `cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed -e s/ph/\\nPH/g | grep -v ^$` to `awk '/physical id/ {f=$0} /core id/ {print f,$0}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> ```
>  cmd = r'cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed -e s/ph/\\nPH/g | grep -v ^$ '
> ```

The r means is a raw string. You might not be escaping some characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose the substitution command for sed with commas ("") to ensure it is passed correctly into python subprocess:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "core id|physical id" | tr -d "\n" | sed -e "s/ph/\\nPH/g" | grep -v ^$ '
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Output:

PHysical id : 0core id      : 0
PHysical id : 0core id      : 0